# Knock 'em down, Knock 'em down

Tags: riddle

All you do is knock me down
Then stand me up again
Then again you knock me down
As for a hint - we're ten.

Comment: I also have an answer for 11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You sound like

> Bowling pins

All you do is knock me down
Then stand me up again
Then again you knock me down
As for a hint - we're ten.

> The game of bowling is played by rolling a ball down a lane to hit the ten pins at the end. The pins are knocked down (or not, in the case of a gutter ball) and then set up again (assuming you're at a bowling alley, this is done by mechanized process, though it could easily be done by hand if you were holding some kind of shady, back-alley bowling league).